# Join 2 nested lists

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I want to combine two lists

```
list_1 <- list(LIST1 = list(list("a"), list("b"), list("c")))
list_2 <- list(LIST2 = list(list("1"), list("2"), list("3")))
```

## Desired Output:

```
combined_list <- list()
combined_list[[1]] <- c("a", "1")
combined_list[[2]] <- c("b", "2")
combined_list[[3]] <- c("c", "3")
```

I have a nasty for loop way of doing this but I'd like to clean it up using purrr maybe? Any help appreciated!!

Comment: This operation is usually known as “zip”, but it seems to be missing from purrr. I thought you could use `map2` but the result of a straightforward call is unintuitively very different.

Comment: … re my previous comment, I missed the redundant intermediate `list`. So `map2` *does* work exactly as expected — e.g. as done in Calum’s answer, or conversely by *first* unlisting and *then* concatenating: `map2(list_1[[1L]], list_2[[1L]], ~ c(unlist(.x), unlist(.y)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a variant that recursively concatenates two nested lists of the same structure and preserves that structure

```
# Add additional checks if you expect the structures of .x and .y may differ
f <- function(.x, .y)
  if(is.list(.x)) purrr::map2(.x, .y, f) else c(.x, .y)

res <- f( list_1, list_2 )
# ...is identical to...
# list(LIST1 = list(list(c("a","1")), list(c("b","2")), list(c("c","3"))))
```

You can then unroll the structure as needed. For example, to get the desired output, you can do

```
purrr::flatten(purrr::flatten(res))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "1"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "b" "2"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "c" "3"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few odd things with your input and so I am not sure if this will wholly generalize to your real situation. If it does not, then please expand your example. Each list has only one element, for one, and the individual letters are also wrapped in a list of their own. I get around that by indexing the input lists with `[[1]]` and flattening the output with `as.character`.

```r
list_1 <- list(LIST1 = list(list("a"), list("b"), list("c")))
list_2 <- list(LIST2 = list(list("1"), list("2"), list("3")))

library(purrr)
combined_list <- map2(list_1[[1]], list_2[[1]], c) %>%
  map(as.character)
str(combined_list)
#> List of 3
#>  $ : chr [1:2] "a" "1"
#>  $ : chr [1:2] "b" "2"
#>  $ : chr [1:2] "c" "3"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use this one line:

```
map2(list_1,list_2,map2,~paste(c(..1,..2)))[[1]]
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "1"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "2"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "3"
```